# How to control newline processing in the lxml xpath text() function?

Tags: python, xpath, newline, lxml, carriage-return

Having switched from Fedora 17 to 18, I get different parsing behaviour for the same lxml code, apparently due to different versions of the underlying libraries (libxml2 and libxslt versions changed).

Here's an example of lxml code with different results for the two versions:

```
from io import BytesIO
from lxml import etree

myHtmlString = \
    '<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">\r\n'+\
    '<html>\r\n'+\
    '<head>\r\n'+\
    '   <title>Title</title>\r\n'+\
    '</head>\r\n'+\
    '<body/>\r\n'+\
    '</html>\r\n'
myFile = BytesIO(myHtmlString)
myTree = etree.parse(myFile, etree.HTMLParser())
myTextElements = myTree.xpath("//text()")
myFullText = ''.join([myEl for myEl in myTextElements])

assert myFullText == 'Title', repr(myFullText)
```

The f17 version passes the assert, i.e. `xpath("//text()")` only returns text `'Title'`, whereas the f18 version fails with output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestLxml.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert myFullText == 'Title', repr(myFullText)
AssertionError: '\r\n\r\n   Title\r\n\r\n\r\n'
```

Apparently, the f18 version handles newlines and whitespace differently from the f17 version.

Is there a way to have control over this behaviour? (An optional argument somewhere?)
Or even better, is there a way in which I can get the old behaviour back using the new libraries?

Answer (score 1):

in XML, the text() returns the text inside the tags as is (unstripped), so if you have any whitespace characters, tabs, new lines they will be included.

It might be that the way you construct the multiline string with + and \n\r accidentally testing two different strings.

If you change your string to a triple quote string like the example below and test it.

```
from io import BytesIO
from lxml import etree


html = '''
    <!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body/>
    </html>
'''
tree = etree.parse(BytesIO(html), etree.HTMLParser())
text_elements = tree.xpath("//text()")
full_text = ''.join(text_elements)
assert full_text == 'Title', repr(full_text)
```

You can also see that surrounding the text with spaces or new lines make them part of the text() function return. See `title` below.

```
html = '''
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html>
<head>
   <title>   Title   </title>
</head>
<body/>
</html>
'''
tree = etree.parse(BytesIO(html), etree.HTMLParser())
text_elements = tree.xpath("//text()")
full_text = ''.join(text_elements)
assert full_text == '   Title   ', repr(full_text)
```

If you don't need the spaces you can always call strip() on the string yourself. If you're sure you're getting spaces even though your tags do not contain them, then you should report that as a bug on the [lxml mailing list](http://lxml.de/index.html#mailing-list).